# Is it possible to test a Firebase trigger locally?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Using `firebase-functions` with Node and `exports.foo = functions.database.ref('/object').onWrite(event => {});`.

I can deploy to the cloud and test just fine ... and I can easily test http-type functions locally using `firebase serve --only functions`.

However, I don't see a way to test **triggers** locally. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This in now possible. I finally find this clear medium post which explain how do it : https://medium.com/@moki298/test-your-firebase-cloud-functions-locally-using-cloud-functions-shell-32c821f8a5ce

To run a trigger locally, use the "functions shell" tool :

1 - My code for firestore (the medium post use RealTime Database) :

```
exports.testTrigger = functions.firestore
.document('messages/{messageId}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    let message = snapshot.data()
    return snapshot.ref.set({
        ...message,
        status : 'sent' 
    })
})
```

2 - I run the firebase shell functions in the terminal

```
firebase functions:shell
```

3 - I call my "testTrigger" cloud function trigger with data in parameter

```
testTrigger({text:"hello"})
```

4- My firestore database has a new "message" updated by my trigger

Answer (score 4):

Very recently, the Firebase team published an update to the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/) the added the ability to invoke other types of triggers locally.  It's documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#use_the_cloud_functions_shell).  Be sure you've updated your CLI to the latest version to get this new functionality:  `npm install -g firebase-tools@latest`

Comment: Not the same thing - invoking a trigger locally `!=` getting the same data you do from a deployed function. What I'd like to see is the locally running server receive the event from the cloud database and invoke the function. What I do now is deploy and watch the logs, which is a pain.

Comment: What you're describing isn't available today, unless you want to write your own code to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Doug answered it in the comment. While invoking a trigger is probably useful in some cases (thanks Doug), it isn't the same as a deployed trigger, which can't be done yet.

So I'll stick with deploying remotely and watching the remote log ... good 'ole Marco Polo debugging.

Comment: Is this possible now? I find the documentation to be a bit ambiguous on this matter, and struggle to get updates when emulating the database triggered functions

Answer (score 2):

Since May 21st 2020 it's now possible to test triggers locally!

See release blog post https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/05/local-firebase-emulator-ui.html

Always good to also take a look at the release notes https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#may_21_2020

And note that 8.4 requires Node 10, as discussed in question [Update of Firebase CLI to 8.4.0 gives errors about "Unsupported engine" saying '{"node":">=10"}'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61943139/update-of-firebase-cli-to-8-4-0-gives-errors-about-unsupported-engine-saying)