# Update of Firebase CLI to 8.4.0 gives errors about "Unsupported engine" saying '{"node":">=10"}'

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cli

After upgrading to 8.4.0 with `npm i -g firebase-tools`, the following is shown:

```
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for google-auth-library@6.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.16.2","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: google-auth-library@6.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for gaxios@3.0.3: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.16.2","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: gaxios@3.0.3
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for gcp-metadata@4.1.0: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.16.2","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: gcp-metadata@4.1.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for gtoken@5.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.16.2","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: gtoken@5.0.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for google-p12-pem@3.0.1: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.16.2","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: google-p12-pem@3.0.1
```

What should I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the release of [Firebase CLI 8.4.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v8.4.0), it appears a lot has changed, including a new [local emulator UI](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/05/local-firebase-emulator-ui.html).  Among the changes are some modules that now require a minimum node version of 10.  That's what the error messages are saying with:

> Unsupported engine for module@version: wanted: {"node":">=10"}

If your local node version is less than 10, you will see these errors.  It's time to upgrade your node version.  If you're using nvm, that's as simple as typing `nvm install 10`.  This does not affect the version of node targeted by Cloud Functions at the time of deployment.  The version of node for deployment is still declared in your package.json.

Comment: I've tried doing this, and checking `npm -v` returns correct npm versions and node is greater than 10, still issues the same error of unsupported version.