# Is it possible to test firebase onUpdate doucment trigger locally?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to test my logic that I have written in the `onUpdate` trigger locally before I deploy my code to dev enviornment. Is it possible that I manually update the document in firebase cloud and trigger the onUpdate running on my local machine ? This is the code that I have

```
export const onFoodExplorerReqUpdated = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: '512MB',
    maxInstances: 6000,
  })
  .firestore.document(`document/{documentId}`)
  .onUpdate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const data = snapshot.after.data()
    console.log(`Data updated, data: ${data}`)
    // my business logic goes here
    return Promise.resolve()
  })
```

I have tried a few things mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614685/is-it-possible-to-test-a-firebase-trigger-locally), but it does not help. New firebase user here

Answer (score 0):

You can run Cloud Functions locally with the [Firebase Emulator Suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite).

If you also configure the emulator to run Cloud Firestore, your functions will trigger based on tht emulated Firestore. If you don't run an emulated Firestore, your functions will trigger against your real Firestore data in the project.